# How can I create an Computer Icon on Windows 8 Server Beta's Desktop?

Tags: shortcuts, windows-8-preview

For some bad reason Microsoft decided to remove all standard desktop icons besides the Recyle bin.

It is easy to create shortcuts to each single disk using create shortcut method.

But I would like to have the computer icon too.

I guess there will be an increased demand to create useful shortcuts on Windows 8 Servers Desktop, because the metro surface 'on the backside of your screen' is just impractical.

**Edit:**
The right click popup menu from desktop looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a shortcut to `explorer.exe shell:MyComputerFolder`. [Here](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-shell-keyword.html)'s a list of `shell:` shortcuts.

On Win7, a shortcut to `explorer.exe` opens up the libraries folder. What does that do in Win8?

Answer (score 1):

I find the old Windows 7 Personalize method works
Right-click the desktop, Personalize

Change Desktop Icons

There are the usual suspects including a Computer icon.

Comment: Please take a second look at http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/evalcenter/hh670538.aspx?ocid=&wt.mc_id=TEC_108_1_33. I refer to Windows Server 8 Beta Datacenter. Build 8250

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command on "run".

It will pop open the "desktop icon settings" without having to install the "Desktop Experience" feature.

> "%Systemroot%\system32\rundll32.exe" shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL
>   desk.cpl,,0

Comment: Hi there... to properly 'blockquote', bold, italicize, etc code snippets, highlight the code, then click the appropriate icon, so the formatting characters get placed in the right location.  Could you re-check your answer to ensure its syntax is correct?  Thank you!

Comment: this solves the actual question, instead of making a shortcut to This PC (which is not the same)